# Inheriting from generic classes in scala

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

Could anyone please explain why the following example code does not compile

```
class Animal(val mass : Int)
class Person(val personMass :Int,val name:String) extends Animal(personMass)

class SocialGroup[T <: Animal]

class AlturisticSocialGroup[T <: Animal ] extends SocialGroup[T]

class Society[A <: SocialGroup[B]]
```

The idea here is that I want a society parameterised by a subclass of SocialGroup. I would like to be able to do

```
val animalSociety : Society[SocialGroup[Animal]] = ......
```

and

```
val niceSociety = Society[AltruisticSocialGroup[Person]] = ....
```

The compiler gives me

> error: not found: type B

I'm sure I am missing something obvious but any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
class Society[A <: SocialGroup[B], B <: Animal]
```

So that you can use

```
val animalSociety: Society[SocialGroup[Animal], Animal] = ...
val niceSociety: Society[AltruisticSocialGroup[Person], Person] = ...
```

You need type parameters `A` ***and*** `B`, so basically you need something like `class ClassName[A, B]` with appropriate properties.

***EDIT:***
Like *@Kigyo* said, you can use anonymous type parameter `_` if you don't need additional restriction on `B`.

```
class Society[A <: SocialGroup[_]]
```

This will replace `B` with the wildcard `_`, which is in turn `_ <: Animal` due to the definition `SocialGroup[T <: Animal]`, and `_` needs no declaration since it has no name, so the code will be shorter.

```
val animalSociety: Society[SocialGroup[Animal]] = ...
val niceSociety: Society[AltruisticSocialGroup[Person]] = ...
```

You can see more explanation in https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html

> Sometimes you do not care to be able to name a type variable, for
>   example:
>
> `scala> def count[A](l: List[A]) = l.size count: [A](List[A])Int`
>
> Instead you can use “wildcards”:
>
> `scala> def count(l: List[_]) = l.size count: (List[_])Int`

Comment: `A <: SocialGroup[_]` should also do it, since there is already the constraint `T <: Animal` in `SocialGroup`.

Comment: @Kigyo OK. I'll add this, too.